# How to find HEXA value of String

Tags: encryption, hash, elliptic-curves

This may be very easy thing, but i am just unable to understand this.

I have a string "Hi", and in `HEXA` its written like this `0111 0010 0111 0011`

Can someone please help me in understanding this conversion.

How do they convert string into `binaries`

Thanks

Comment: Two questions about how much you know: 1) Do you know what ASCII is? 2) Do you know how to convert between decimal, binary and hexadecimal?

Comment: Thanks- I know `ASCII`, but don't know about conversion.

Comment: "Hi" actually isn't `0111 0010 0111 0011`. Was that just an example for a binary sequence or did you want to say "Hi"=`0111 0010 0111 0011` and if so where did you get that number from?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with cryptography. It's about computer usage and basic data representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, let's start from the beginning then.

The string "Hi" is actually encoded as `{0x48,0x69}` [(as per the ASCII table)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_table#ASCII_printable_code_chart), so a string-number array conversion is as simple as a bunch of table look-ups.

Now converting between hexadecimal and binary and back is easy. Just note that each hexadecimal character corresponds to exactly four bits in binary (because there are $16=2^4$ possible hexadecimal values). So you can map `0x4` to an actual `0100`, `0x8` to `1000`, `0x6` to `0110` and `0x9` to `1001` resulting in the overall sequence `0100 1000 0110 1001` for the string "Hi".

The opposite direction is just as obvious, you just group your bits in groups of four and read each hexadecimal character from this and split between each pair of characters and do a reverse-look-up in the table.

However, sometimes you're not given the luxury of a Wikipedia ASCII table with hexadecimal entries but have to live with decimal entries, for example `{72,105}`. In this case the easiest strategy is to just subtract the largest power of 2 fitting. For example `72-64=8` (take note: `1000000`) and `8-8=0` (take note: `1001000`) and you're done. Now repeat this process for `105` and you should get `110 1001` and finally fill all the bit strings up to byte-size by adding leading zeroes and concatenate everything (nice byte-level grouping will increase the readability): "Hi"=`0100 1000 0110 1001`.

The reverse is even easier. You always take a group of eight bits and then start from right to left and compute $\sum_{i=0}^7{b_i\cdot 2^i}$ to get the decimal representation, or in easier words: Multiply the i-th bit (from the right) with the i-th power of 2 and add everything together (with zero-based indices).